# I followed an FTP setup guide to try and setup FTP and now I have to enter my password for every file I want to access

Tags: permissions, password, ftp, authentication, vsftpd

Yesterday I tried to setup an FTP server and I almost got it but no luck. Now all my permissions are screwed up. Whenever I try to access my video files I am asked for password authentication for every file.

I ran `ls-la` and it showed me that everything is user 'eric' except: drwxr-xr-x  5 root root (which I'm assuming is root).

Don't understand Linux much but I've been using it (GUI) for two decades. So when I try to configure something in terminal I just follow guides (almost always something goes wrong).

Any clues where I could look next to solve this? Since my attempt at the FTP server never quite worked, I would be willing to undo everything I did if there is a way to do that.

Comment: What asks you for password? How did you configure it? Which ftp server are you using? Why do you want ftp, and not a sane protocol such as sftp or smb?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  e RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Wow, pretty quick replies, thanks. Just to be clear, this question is not about making my FTP work (I actually used SFTP), that'll be another project because I'm almost there. However, the FTP setup was relevant to my question because it is the only configuration that changed before I had my problem. When I try to access video files on my hdd

Comment: ...on my hdd it asks for a password. I don't want that. Pretty sure it has to do with my users and permission setup which I messed with twice—once following these instructions https://bit.ly/3lRmwJc and the second when my friend told me i should make my pw harder